# Experience manager and angular.js

Tags: experience-manager

I have a HTML page(Main), which is referring another HTML page(Second) for main content (excluding Header and Footer) and framework used in Angular.js.In one of the CT of second HTML , I have editable fields. When I am trying to edit Main page in XPM , I am not able to edit Component. Now when I inspect my main page, I am not able to see the field markup instead it shows the reference to second page only. Is Angular.js framework the reason for this?

On more thing I observed is when I open XPM for main page, it shows me second page in breadcrumb instead of Index page (image 2). 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First thing to make sure when you are using a multiple page setup, is to make sure you are enabling editing of the right Page. In your case I would say that is the content Page (second HTML page), since that is where your (editable) Components are on.

So then you need to make sure that the XPM Page markup is only available for that second page. When you have multiple XPM Page Settings, you will definitely get strange (unwanted) behavior.

Furthermore, when you want to edit fields, you need to make sure that you have both the `Start Component Presentation` and the `Start Component Field` markup on your Page, and the `Start Component Presentation` markup need to be around the `Start Component Field` markup. Each markup needs to be in their own HTML container (like a `div` or `span` tag) and of course the markup needs to be valid.

Last thing I can mention is that all of this information needs to be on the page at the right time, as XPM will index your page and inspect the available markup when it loads the page (which is right after the HTML DOM is loaded). Any markup you add afterwards via AJAX or something, will be too late for XPM, and thus those items will not appear editable.

This all being said, I hope you have some pointers to get your problem solved, if not, by all means edit your question and provide more detail, so we can answer it in more detail too.

Comment: There is a way to have XPM index after AJAX content is loaded: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/edit-ajax-loaded-content-with-experience-manager-really - note this method is once per page - so its not possible to have it update content and thus XPM markup after interaction with the page

Comment: Nice suggestion @WillPrice, I can see that coming in handy